# How can i copy tab seperated contents from txt file into Hashmaps?

Tags: java, hashmap

For example

```
FirstName LastName Balance
Bob     Blue        24.98
Steve   Green       345.98
Pam     White       0.00
Sue     Red         42.16
```

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ();
String data;
System.out.println("please enter the file path");
File myObj = new File(scanner.nextLine());
Scanner scan = new Scanner(myObj);
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    data = scan.nextLine();
    list.add(data);
}
```

I want the FirstName, LastName and Balance to be the keys and the rest contents to be the values.

Comment: Provide the attempt you've made.

Comment: Where you are getting value like this? is it JSON OR just a String?

Comment: From a txt file i get this values

Comment: I use this code to get the values from txt file and store the values in a list





 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String data;
        System.out.println("please enter the file path");
        File myObj = new File(scanner.nextLine());
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(myObj);

        while (scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            data = scan.nextLine();
            list.add(data);
        }

Comment: @XristosDjArchie, Do you want to have a three items which include keys FirstName, LastName, Balance, and other values are list of each key.

Comment: OR Do you want a list of object which holds the values Bob, Blue, 24.98

Comment: @Ganesa Vijayakumar i want to have three items which include keys FirstName, LastName, Balance, and other values list of each key

Answer (score 0):

I have made the code to answer your question and also I have slightly changed the format of the .txt file (Hence, Each value is separated by space (" ") both heading and also values). I have given below the two files and also provided the expected output. I hope this will help you to proceed. Please let me know if you have any queries on the answer.

**FileReader.java**

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileReader {
        public static void main(final String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
                final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter the file path");
                final String path = sc.next();
                File file = new File(path);
                Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
                String[] keys = fileScanner.nextLine().split(" ");
                List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<>();
                List<String> lastNames = new ArrayList<>();
                List<String> balances = new ArrayList<>();
                while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
                        String values[] = fileScanner.nextLine().split(" ");
                        firstNames.add(values[0]);
                        lastNames.add(values[1]);
                        balances.add(values[2]);
                }
                Map<String, List<String>> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
                fileMap.put(keys[0], firstNames);
                fileMap.put(keys[1], lastNames);
                fileMap.put(keys[2], balances);
                fileMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
                sc.close();
                fileScanner.close();
        }
}
```

**TextFile.txt**

```
FirstName LastName Balance
Bob Blue 24.98
Steve Green 345.98
Pam White 0.00
Sue Red 42.16
```

**Expected output:**

```
Please enter the file path
*\GitHub\playground\gvlab\src\TextFile.txt
FirstName=[Bob, Steve, Pam, Sue]
LastName=[Blue, Green, White, Red]
Balance=[24.98, 345.98, 0.00, 42.16]
```